# Opscode Chef nginx compile from source issue reports successful run but does nothing

Tags: nginx, automation, infrastructure, chef

I am trying to install nginx from source in Opscode Chef and its bit weird, it runs complaining nothing but does not install it either.

This is how my role attributes look like looks like

```
"nginx":{
    "default_site_enabled":false,
    "version":"1.2.6",
    "init_style":"init",
    "install_method":"source",
    "configure_flags":[
        "--without-http_access_module",
        "--without-http_auth_basic_module",
        "--without-http_autoindex_module",
        "--without-http_browser_module",
        "--without-http_charset_module",
        "--without-http_fastcgi_module",
        "--without-http_memcached_module",
        "--without-http_referer_module",
        "--without-http_scgi_module",
        "--without-http_split_clients_module"

    ],
    "log_dir":"/var/log/nginx",
    "binary":"/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx",
    "source":{
        "prefix":"/opt/nginx/dist",
        "modules":["http_ssl_module",
                   "http_gzip_static_module"

                  ]

    }
},
```

The chef log shows:

```
 [2012-12-19T02:37:44+00:00] INFO: Processing bash[compile_nginx_source] action run (nginx::source line 82)
 [2012-12-19T02:37:45+00:00] INFO: bash[compile_nginx_source] ran successfully
```

I am clueless on what's going on :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very crazy bug in nginx recipe (as described here: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx/pull/13)

The problem is with including version attribute in role attributes. Just remove that and it will work.

This indeed took lot of time for me to figureout, I hope this information saves time for someone else here.

---

There is open bug here https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx/pull/14 related to this.

To get past this issue , your best bet can be to use 0.99.2 version of the recipie